# Odmantic models Inheritence from pydantic models

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pydantic

Hello dear community,

I am working with engine for mongodb operations and i have an odmantic model that inherit from a pydantic model.

```
OdmanticModel(Model, PydanticModel):
      attributes
```

It seems that odmantic model does not considerate pydantic model attribute, and these are not saved eventually in mongodb.
Is there any solution or a workarround to make the inheritance fully worked implicitly or explicitly

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative for the solution, i used Beanie ODM, it is perfect when it comes to pydantic and mongodb models interactions.

*Beanie - is an Asynchronous Python object-document mapper (ODM) for MongoDB, based on Motor and Pydantic.*